# I want to use SSRS map local report on asp.net mvc razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reporting-services-map

I have created local report containing map. My database is in MySql so I have used ODBC connector for MySql. I have also rendered local report on razor view. But can't render the map report. So how to render that map report locally programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First time I was struggling with bug of Visual Studio that when I assign local report to Report Viewer and then assign Datasource for that report it always gets close automatically. So my report can't get its datasource. So for that I have put my DataSource first and configure that DataSource by clicking its "Configure DataSource" button. Then its code was added in code behind file. Now I can show my report on view page. But I recommend who wants to use world map or any country's map for their project google's "Geo Chart". In google Geo Chart is different than Google Map. Geo chart is simple to integrate.